# Error in finding optimal n_estimators via xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

Beginner here.
I'm trying to find the best number of n_estimators using xgboost.

But, I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb5Dz.jpg).

```
diabetes.head() #this is a toy dataset in sklearn.datasets.
```

[diabetes.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBk2N.jpg)

```
x=diabetes.drop('y',axis=1).values
y=diabetes.y.values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,random_state=16,test_size=0.25)

import xgboost as xgb
xgbmodel=xgb.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:squarederror",eval_metric='rmse',early_stopping_rounds=10,n_estimators=1000,random_state=16)
xgbmodel.fit(x_train,y_train,eval_set=[x_test,y_test])
```

I think the problem lies within:

> eval_set=[x_test,y_test]

P.S. I double checked that diabetes dataset from sklearn can used used for regression.I was wondering if my error lies within eval_metric method.

**Full error here:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10180/532743731.py in <module>
      4 import xgboost as xgb
      5 xgbmodel=xgb.XGBRegressor(objective="reg:squarederror",eval_metric='rmse',early_stopping_rounds=10,n_estimators=1000,random_state=16)
----> 6 xgbmodel.fit(x_train,y_train,eval_set=[x_test,y_test])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    530         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    531             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 532         return f(**kwargs)
    533 
    534     return inner_f

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
    929         """
    930         evals_result: TrainingCallback.EvalsLog = {}
--> 931         train_dmatrix, evals = _wrap_evaluation_matrices(
    932             missing=self.missing,
    933             X=X,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in _wrap_evaluation_matrices(missing, X, y, group, qid, sample_weight, base_margin, feature_weights, eval_set, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, eval_group, eval_qid, create_dmatrix, enable_categorical)
    434 
    435         evals = []
--> 436         for i, (valid_X, valid_y) in enumerate(eval_set):
    437             # Skip the duplicated entry.
    438             if all(

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965968/error-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-3) There are dozens of other questions concerning the "ValueError: too many values to unpack" problem, read a few of them and you'll find the problem yourself. As a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it has to be a tuple, see below, your x_test, y_test should be enclosed in parentheses

```
eval_setparam = [(self.X_valid, self.y_valid)]
        
xg_model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train,  
                     eval_set = eval_setparam,
                     verbose=False)
```

Comment: this really helped me a lot. It was a minute mistake which I kept doing for hours. Thanks for the input.